# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

After adding some nuget packages, my asp.net core app has stopped working and started to generate this error once deployed to Amazon windows server [Works OK on my dev machine (as always :-)].

Visual Studio: 2019

Target Framework: netcoreapp3.1

Installed: dotnet-hosting-5.0.7 + dotnet-sdk-5.0.401

in my deps.json file, the Microsoft.Extensions.Options always appear in the right version (3.1.10) and never in 5.0.0 version.

Any ideas where the problem might come from?

Comment: Are the prerequisite dependencies of Microsoft.Extensions.Options correct? Can you show the csproj configuration file on your server?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. The error is:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

The fix: upgrade Microsoft.Extensions.Options in Nuget from version 2.x.x to latest version (version 5.0.0) and delete all obj and bin folders and rebuild.

My projects are on .NET Framework 4.7.2. When Microsoft.Extensions.Options get updated, several other Nuget packages that were also on version 2.x.x also got updated.

Answer (score -1):

After uninstalling most of the Nuget packages and reinstalling them with the right version, the problem was resolved.

Comment: What versions are the right versions?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to mention what were the right versions...